# Import R with downloaded source code

Tags: android, r.java-file

I've downloaded the ContactsList example from google's developer site. When creating a new project with this code, I've got several errors, and I realized that all are because the same thing: It doesn't get the R resources, so it is importing the android.R.

I've tryed celaning the project, trying to solve layout's issues if the had, etc.. but still doesn't create the R.java file in "gen".

So, I don't know what I'm forgoting to do because I tought that code downloaded directly from google should work fine.

Comment: Could you please post these errors?

Comment: simple restarting eclipse a few times might help!

Comment: restarted but continues. The error is the tipical "cannot be resolved or is not a field" in all the definitions like (R.layout.XXX, or R.bool.XXX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the following:

1. Check whether there is error in your xml file.
2. Check whether you are missing any jar(additional) file.
3. Try to change your target sdk to some other and change to original.

Comment: The project comes with a "android-support-v4.jar" library in the libs folder. Do I have to add this somewhere?

Comment: Right click project go to "properties" and check f whether ther si some error(Showing red mark for additional libraries) .If not try to change the target device..

Comment: Right click project and in that android choose some other devices(i think you have more than devices) and see..

Comment: Works now with a Higher API. Thanks